# Security Suggestion API

Tags: api, security, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint Online application that access an API the reside outside my network and one of our Azure. This API is accessibly through public. I am using this API to access data in my SQL server, with this I am worried that my API is not secure and I am wonder what are the things I can do to secure my API so that no only users logged in to our SharePoint can use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways in which you can secure it. These ways vary in complexity and each have their specific considerations.

**Secure an API with Azure AD**

If you're using Office 365, securing custom APIs using Azure AD is an architectural option that you should definitely consider. First and foremost, it allows you to secure the access to the API using existing organizational credentials that are already managed through Office 365 and Azure AD. Users with an active account can seamlessly work with applications that leverage APIs secured with Azure AD. Azure AD administrators can centrally manage access to the API, the same way they manage access to all other applications registered with Azure AD.

More info: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-api-secured-with-aad)